# Clearing the search history from a webview

Tags: android, browser, webview, android-webview, browser-history

[image]

In my implementation, I want to remove this search history from the google page.
I had tried with cache clear, clear form data, clearHistory but not succeed.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the history of your Webview or browser, it is being saved on your particular Google account, for that, I guess you have to delete Google Search History from your Google account.

[How to delete all google search history](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/465)

Or try clearing all data from webView using `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();`